# An exponential polynomial with at least one bounded positivity component

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, tag-removed

In a forthcoming paper on nodal domains of Gaussian random functions, we (I and Misha Sodin) have a statement that is, roughly speaking, the following: if bounded nodal domains are possible at all, they have certain positive density. This sounds great until one asks a naive question "When are they possible at all?". Stripped of all irrelevant high tech terminology, this boils down to the following:

Let $K$ be an origin symmetric compact set in $\mathbb R^n$ having no isolated points and not contained in a hyperplane. Can one always construct a real-valued trigonometric polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{y\in K}\;c_y\; e^{i\,y\cdot x}$ (where all but finitely many $c_y$ vanish and $c_{-y}=\bar c_y$) such that the set $f\ge 0$ has at least one bounded connected component? If not, how to describe $K$ for which it is possible?

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by $e^{i(y,x)}$?

Comment: presumably exp[ i * <y,x> ] where <y,x> is the standard Euclidean inner product?

Comment: He uses cdot a few times in this one: http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4237 but typically uses langle y,x rangle for, say, Fourier transform. 

Comment: Yes, it is $i$ (square root of $-1$) times the usual scalar product of $x$ and $y$. This time I was just a bit lazy to type langle and rangle and thought that the (,) notation would do. Well, a lazy person does everything twice, indeed :). Today I also noticed that just the hyperplane condition isn't quite enough but I'll be almost equally happy with "not contained in finitely many hyperplanes" or "has a point no neighborhood of which is contained in a hyperplane" as a condition.

Comment: @PietroMajer Could you, please, finish the sentence? :-)

Comment: Sorry, I had a chair accident ;) I'm OK. I expanded the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's denote $F_K$ the family of real-valued trigonometric polynomials corresponding to $K$, and assume that *$K$ has a point in the interior of its convex envelope.* Then,  there is a function $f$ in $F_K$ for which $\{f\ge 0\}$ has a bounded component.

To show this we can freely apply a linear transformation to $K$, for $F_{LK}=\{f\circ L^T\, :\, f\in F_K \}$. In particular we can assume that $K$ includes the standard basis $ \{  e_1,\dots,  e_n\}$, and there is in $K$ one more point $y $ with $y_j\ge0$ and $\|y\|_1:=\sum_{j=1}^n y_j <1$. Consider a trigonometric polynomial
$$f(x)= \sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_j  \cos(x_j) -\cos(y\cdot x)\, .$$
It belongs to $F_K$ and has a second-order  expansion at $0$
$$f(x)=  \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j - 1  -  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n  \lambda_j x_j^2  +  \frac{1}{2}(y\cdot x)^2+o(\|x\|^2)$$
$$\le  \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j - 1\Big)   -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n  (\lambda_j  -\|y\|_1y_j)x_j^2  +o(\|x\|^2) $$
because by Cauchy-Schwarz, $(y\cdot x)^2 = \big( \sum_{j=1}^n  y_j ^{1/2} y_j ^{1/2} x_j\big)^2\le \|y\|_1\sum_{j=1}^n  y_j x_j^2  $.

We can now take e.g. $\lambda_j=  \|y\|_1y_j +\frac{1}{ n}(1-\|y\|_1^2+\epsilon)$  with $\epsilon>0$ so that $f(0)=\epsilon$ and $f(x)\le\epsilon-\frac{1}{2n}(1-\|y\|_1^2)\|x\|^2+o(\|x\|^2)$ (unif. on $\epsilon$). So for $\epsilon$ small enough   $f(x)<0$ on the boundary of a  ball around $0$, meaning that the connected component of $0$ in $\{f\ge0\}$ is contained in the ball.

Comment: this condition   can be weakened  a little more if we use more general $f$ in the above argument. For instance, a sufficient  condition, always assuming wlog $\pm e_j\in K$  is:
$$\mathrm{int} (\mathrm{co}(K))\cap S^{-1}\mathrm{co}(S(K))\neq\emptyset$$ where $S$ is the map $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto(x_1^2,\dots,x_n^2)$.  However sated this way the latter is not invariant by linear transformations .